# AR(2) process with arima.sim function

Tags: r

I need to generate AR(2) process `Y[t]=4+0.5Y[t-1]-0.3Y[t-2]+e[t] e[t]~(0,4)`.

I tried with `arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(.5,-0.3)),n=200)` but I don't know how to add 4 and variance of residuals also 4.

Comment: If the mean is 4, just add that to the process. You can set the variance with`sd=` option.

Comment: Aye, just as easy as Khashaa said: `arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(.5,-0.3)),n=200, sd = 4) + 4`

Comment: I see that mean is clearly not 4, it is rather 4/0.8=5.